# Can someone execute a php function in my library but not called on the viewed page?

Tags: php, code-injection

Let's say I have a php file, test.php with 2 functions: test1() and test2().

If I have an external php file, index.php, with include(test.php) in its code. If in the index.php file has a reference to test1() but not test2(), is there any way that someone would be able to execute test2() by doing something malicious while using the index.php file?

Comment: No. (Reputation isn't deserved for such a short answer, so I'm commenting and not answering.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way they could execute arbitrary code is through a [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) vulnerability.

Here's an oversimplified example:

```
<?php

$runthis = $_GET["runthis"];

$runthis();
```

So an attacker could invoke your script as `http://example.com/index.php?runthis=test2` and then it would run your `test2()` function.

Read more about code injection at the wikipedia article I linked to above, or at the [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection) site.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "using", do you mean like an end user in their browser? No, they can't run arbitrary code.